# Cannot use jQuery ajaxComplete in a content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to add a simple content script to a tab that triggers when all jquery ajax requests are done.
When I open pages with jQuery ajax (for example: http://demos.9lessons.info/wall/index1.php) nothing happens.

I have the following code:

## main.js

```
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.10.2.min.js'), data.url('tab.js')]});
```

## tab.js

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {alert('Ajax complete')});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interact with the instance of jQuery running in the page (if any), not the one in your content script.

`main.js`

```
const {data} = require("self");
const {PageMod} = require("sdk/page-mod");

PageMod({
  include: "http://demos.9lessons.info/wall/index1.php",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("alert.js"),
  contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});
```

`alert.js`

```
if (unsafeWindow.jQuery) {
    unsafeWindow.jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() { alert("complete"); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this does not work, it only works for the first ajax on the page. If I issue other ajax requests later, I don't get the alert box.